# Cannot convert value of type [AnyObject] to expected argument type [PFObject] -- Parse & Swift II Error

Tags: swift, parse-platform, swift2

This is the line that is failing, with error message "Cannot convert value of type [AnyObject] to expected argument type [PFObject]"

self.customObtainAllHandlerWithObjects(objects, success: success, failure: failure)

---

import UIKit
import Parse

class AbstractService: BaseService {

```
private let _cache = AbstractCache<T>()
private let _parser = AbstractParser<T>()

/// Store all completionHandlers for convertFromParseObject operations here. Need this to avoid a concurrent conversions of the same object.
var conversions = Dictionary<String, [(entity: T) -> Void]>()

/// Contains ids of objects, which need their videos to be downloaded.
var queue: [(entityId: String, file: PFFile)] = []
var isQueueDownloading = false

var className: String {
    get {
        fatalError("This property must be overridden")
    }
}

// MARK: - Create

func createEntity() -> T {
    let entity = T()
    cache().appendEntity(entity)
    return entity
}

// MARK: - Obtain all

/// Base method, which obtains entities from Parse database.
///
/// - parameter skip: Number of records, which will be skipped.
/// - parameter limit: Max number of entities returned.
/// - parameter constraints: A block, which applies constraints to PFQuery. E.g. query.includeKey("author") or query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()).
/// - parameter success: Success block. Executes when operation successfully finished.
/// - parameter failure: Failure block. Executes when operation fails.

func obtain(skip skip: Int?, limit: Int?, constraints applyConstraints: ((query: PFQuery) -> PFQuery)?, success: (entities: [T]) -> Void, failure: FailureCompletionHandler) {
    var query = PFQuery(className: className)
    if let skip = skip {
        query.skip = skip
    }
    query.limit = limit ?? 1000
    if let applyConstraints = applyConstraints {
        query = applyConstraints(query: query)
    }
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            self.callFailureCompletionHandler(failure, error: error)
        }
        else {
            if let objects = objects {
                self.customObtainAllHandlerWithObjects(objects, success: success, failure: failure)
            }
            else {
                failure(allowRetry: false, errorMessage: "Cannot load \(self.className)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do NOT use screenshots to present your code: If one wanted to validate it, the good soul would have to retype it. Furthermore, it is hard to read. Please add a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_.

Comment: Ops, sorry. Should have done a better job looking through the getting started guides. Extremely frustrated trying to figure this out and was looking for a quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because *object* is of type **[AnyObject]** but the function you're calling--customObtainHandler--is expecting **PFObject** so you're going to have to convert your *object* to a **PFObject**.

You can convert between types with the **as** keyword.

so you do something like this:

```
if let myVar as? PFObject {
    // now myVar is a PFObject
}
```

I don't recommend this but you can also force convert it using:

```
myVar as! PFObject
```